# 'libxml2' file not found

Tags: c++

I'm using Ubuntu and I get the above error message in Emacs when I try `#include <libxml2>` in my .cpp file. I already have libxml2 and libxml2-dev installed to the newest versions and the language server recognises it as I type. Is it necessary to have more include statements or is there some other problem?

EDIT: As I'm trying to parse HTML files I included the libxml/HTMLparser.h header file and Emacs flycheck showed an error saying that xmlversion.h couldn't be found in that file, so I added that and then it said xmlexports.h couldn't be found in xmlversion.h so I added that. However now it's still saying that xmlexports.h can't be found even though I've added it. What's going on here?
[Emacs showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2smB2.png)

Comment: Generally the include files for libxml2 are installed under `/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/` and to include a specific file you would, e.g. `#include <libxml/parser.h>` On your system, check with `dpkg -L libxml2-dev | grep include`. Then make sure you set the include search path as part of your compile string, e.g. `-I/usr/include/libxml2`.

Comment: I've put `#include </usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h>` and now I get an error saying ***In included file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found*** even though xmlversion.h does show up  when I run `dpkg -L libxml2-dev | grep include`

Comment: You need, e.g. `#include <libxml/parser.h>` (whatever include file you need -- `parser.h` is just one of 20 or so), AND you need `-I/usr/include/libxml2` to tell the compiler to start looking for your include files at `/usr/include/libxml2`. Then when you link you need `-lxml2` to link against the library. Check the documentation for whatever libxml2 function you are using and it will tell you what include is needed. libxml2 also comes with a `pkg-config` file, so you can include `\`pkg-config --cflags libxml-2.0\`` to have it spit out `-I/usr/include/libxml2` for you -- up to you.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; `-I/usr/include/libxml2`, where does this go, back into the terminal or into my .cpp file? I'm trying to get data from HTML tables so I'm assuming the parser is the file I need.

Comment: `-I/some/dir` is what you add to your *compiler command*. Like `gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/libxml2 -o yourexename -lxml2 yoursource.c` which tells the compiler to search under `/usr/include/libxml2` to find your header and `-lxml2` tells the linker to link with libxml2 when linking the final executable to produce `yourexename` (whatever name you want to give it) If you post your code (a minimum reproducible example), I'll help figure out what you need to compile/link it -- but right now I can only guess what header you may need.

Comment: It does compile fine but the language server doesn't recognise any of the classes etc. that I'm trying to use as it's insisting that it can't find the file. Is there any way to fix this? I'm using libxml2/HTMLparser.h

Comment: Make sure you include ALL the needed headers. There are `48` individual headers for libxml2 of which `parser.h` is just `1`. You will need to either read the documentation for the class you are using to know which headers are needed OR you could just `grep` the header files for the class and then make an educated judgement based on the result. My reference to `parser.h` was just as an example. The other possibility is compiling is fine, but is cannot find the library and the link fails. Check with `pkg-config --libs libxml-2.0` to see if `-lxml2` is correct for Ubuntu. Also `-L/path/to/libdir`